# CSS widths and columns issue

Tags: html, css

*I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.* I'm working with the widths and margins of a three column layout and I want to widen the right sidebar into the white space to the left.

But when I increase the width of #sidebar-right above 22%, both sidebars drop down below the content. I'm missing something having to do with the combined widths and margins.

HTML and CSS are below the image. This is also a responsive structure, if that makes a difference. I need to stay with this CSS and HTML as it is a WordPress theme, and I don't want to move into another type of CSS column or box structure.

**Update 10/23/12**  *I gave up on trying to adapt the current CSS and HTML and changed to box layout model CSS for page templates because the box model works well and I am able to simplify my page templates, too.*

Any ideas?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
    <body class="three-column">

    <div id="page">
    <div id="main">
    <div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar-right">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar-left">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>
    </div>
    </div> (some closing divs omitted for clarity).
```

**CSS:**

```
#page {
margin: 1em auto;
max-width: 1075px;
}

#main #secondary {
float: none;
margin: 0 7.6%;
width: auto;
}

.three-column #page {
max-width: 1075px;
}

.three-column #primary {
float: left;
margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

.three-column #content {
margin: 0 34% 0 20%;
width: 44%;
border:1px solid #c2c2c2;
padding:10px;
}

.three-column #sidebar-right {
float: right;
margin-right: 1.5%;
width: 22%;
border:1px solid #c2c2c2;
padding:10px;
}

.three-column #sidebar-left{
position:relative;
float: left;
width: 15%;
margin-left: -72%;
border:1px solid #c2c2c2;
padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox should solve the problem. http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: Have you tried border-box box sizing? It should work perfectly and make it so that each column is, including padding, margins, etc., the specified width. You should also try defining a width for the center column.

Comment: The hyphens in your margin property values are new to me. What do they do?

Comment: One problem is that instead of giving #primary the proper width, you have set negative margins to accommodate the other elements. I recommend you simply assign the correct widths based on the ratio you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is the -26.4% right margin on #primary and the -72% left margin on #sidebar-left.

I've made a Fiddle with those adjusted; I dropped the side-bar left left margin (but kept 1.5% for padding's sake), and adjusted #primary's right margin to -100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/CtkyN/1/

This is still pretty darn hack-y. If there's any way you can, you'll have a much better experience re-working the HTML and CSS.. but if not, that fiddle will at least allow you to re-size the right sidebar as you want within this existing framework.

**Update:** I don't have credible sources, but I can explain the CSS math. In general, you're using negative margins on #primary to lay the other two divs in areas #primary would normally occupy. Normally, the only way to make divs overlap like this would be by setting them to `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`. Because those are so hard, a layout like this would normally be accomplished with three left floats (or in the future, flexbox), but because of the order of your HTML that's not possible.

Instead, you're forced to convince the CSS renderer that #primary doesn't mind being over-laid... which you do by setting a negative margin of -100%, essentially saying, "Here, have all this space, it's fine for you to overlap it." Once you've opened up the space, you then use the left and right floats (and the width constriction) to place the sidebars in the blank spaces on either side of #content.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much works, and I should have used a fiddle to begin with (I have been using them for javascript). I've been staying with the CSS because it's a Wordpress theme that I'm adapting to two sidebars, even though it's wacky. Right now with your mods, the only thing that doesn't work is the content covers the right sidebar when the browser shrinks below 750px wide. Is there a way to keep the middle content div responsive? Not a huge deal, but 750px seems like its too wide for mobiles.

Comment: Are there some examples out there that would be responsive with three columns like this without the wacky negative margins, etc.? Maybe I should start from scratch.

Comment: Here's one of the simplest examples: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/cf6Yz/  One awkward thing about doing it this way is that you have to subtract your column margins from the width of each column. If you'd like to avoid that, we can do it with an extra set of divs for each column, and then using padding for our spacing.

Comment: @songdogtech Get a chance to look at it?

Comment: Matt, thanks for the help. The fiddle you set up with the existing CSS and HTML works in the fiddle, but for some reason on my localhost site, the left sidebar still overflows into the content. The twentyeleven layout code I started with is pretty good to begin with, but I was trying to add a left sidebar. So I gave up on the messy code and went with box layout model in your second fiddle because the page templates I need for the site are very simple and I can get away with simplifying the layout. So thanks, and the box layout model works well and is responsive.  -- Mark

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I did a three column layout that might work for you.

HTML

```
<body class="three-column">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="primary">
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="sidebar-left">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.
                    </div>

                    <div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.
                    </div>

                    <div id="sidebar-right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border:0;
    width: 80%;
}

#sidebar-left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;   
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#sidebar-right {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#content { 
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

I also noticed that having a border cause problems for the layout.  May be adding following will help to keep the border inside the div.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

[See this article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is specifically here:

```
.three-column #content {
margin: 0 34% 0 20%;
}
```

margin: top right bottom left;

so you have to decrease the right margin to let the right sidebar expand.
din't try it. you better test it.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:-

**HTML**

```
<body class="three-column">

    <div id="page">
    <div id="main">
    <div id="primary">
    <div id="sidebar-left">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div> 
    <div id="content" role="main">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar-right">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>


    </div>
    </div> (some closing divs omitted for clarity).
```

**CSS**

```
#page {
margin: 1em auto;
max-width: 1075px;
}

#main #secondary {
float: none;
margin: 0 7.6%;
width: auto;
}

.three-column #page {
max-width: 1075px;
}

.three-column #primary {
float: left;
margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

.three-column #sidebar-left{
position:relative;
float: left;
width: 15%;
}

.three-column #content {
margin: 0 34% 0 20%;
width: 44%;
border:1px solid #c2c2c2;
padding:10px;
float: left;
}

.three-column #sidebar-right {
float: left;
margin-right: 1.5%;
width: 22%;
border:1px solid #c2c2c2;
padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy actually your very near you forgot that padding is adding to the width of your content so if you have 3 divs with 20% width and 10% margin & 10% padding on each side you would get beyond the 100% you have to move with.

Working JSfiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NETse/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given you the explanation. I just wanted to add the visual representation to make it easier to see the problem.
[image: The problem area]

Answer (score 0):

`.three-column #content` div is the middle content it need to have margin left as `#sidebar-left` div width + padding and margin right as `#sidebar-right` div width + padding and no need to fix the width for the middle content.

Check the [sample](http://jsbin.com/okedox/1) and [code](http://jsbin.com/okedox/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I did not see the comment that you had to stay with the same CSS.  Possibly this can be used in addition to what you currently have, but if not please disregard.

If you use a row-fluid along with div spans you can scale them without having as many issues. The CSS is in fiddler.

http://jsfiddle.net/GeyHC/1/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2" id="content" role="main" style="border:1px solid #c2c2c2;">

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
        quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
        imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
        et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>

    <div class="span6" id="sidebar-right" style="border:1px solid #c2c2c2;">

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
        quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
        imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
        et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>

    <div class="span2 offset1" id="sidebar-left" style="border:1px solid #c2c2c2;">

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Mauris a eros eu sem sollicitudin vulputate. Maecenas ac ante libero,
        quis volutpat diam. Etiam eleifend arcu eu enim tincidunt ornare. Sed
        imperdiet viverra bibendum. Proin a enim et turpis tempus mattis vitae
        et ipsum. In et ligula eget tellus malesuada pretium sed ut ipsum.

    </div>
</div>
​
```